# Select the used and not used Rows from Foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, oracle

well I have the following tables.

```
components (prodNo, compNo, partNo)
parts (partNo, partName)
products (prodNo, prodName)
```

I need to select the parts that are being used OR not being used to manufacture the different product.

I can select the parts that are being used but dont know how to include the not used parts in the result.

Anyways, the result should be in following pattern

**Result**

```
prodNo, prodName, partNo, partName, compNo, status
101     A           23     G         55      YES
NULL    NULL        20     I         NULL    NO
34      F           555    S         58      YES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the parts table as the core of the query and make outer joins with the corresponding components and products tables

```
Select products.prodNo, products.prodName, parts.partNo, parts.partName, components.compNo,
case when NVL(products.prodNo,0) > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as status
from parts 
left outer join components on components.partNo = parts.partNo
left outer join products on products.prodNo = components.prodNo
```

Comment: it never says NO. it just excludes the parts that are not used

Comment: And you are sure that there are parts that don't have a connection to components? select count(*)
from parts
where parts.prodNo not in (
select components.partNo
from components)

Comment: hmmm..It should be included. If you run this: Select *
from parts 
left outer join components on components.partNo = parts.partNo
left outer join products on products.prodNo = components.prodNo; it should include all parts even if they don't have a corresponding row in components or products

Comment: yes, this one shows all the records with one row containing NULLs - means, this part is not being used

Comment: @muaaz Ok, Then the problem has to be in the case when where I put the condition on prodNo. I have updated my answer, could you run the query and se if it gets you the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.prodNo,prd.prodName,prt.partNo,prt.partName,p.compNo,IF (p.prodNo IS NULL,"NO","YES") as status 
from components as p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts prd as p.partNo = prd.partNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products prt on p.prodNo = prt.prodNo
```

Comment: IF (p.prodNo IS NULL,"NO","YES") as status use this in your query will it work ?